# Convert .m4r/.mp3 to .caf/.aiff in iphone app

Tags: iphone

As of right now I am using ffmpeg to convert from .mp3 --> to .aiff but I would like a native way to do this in xcode but i do not understand how to use AudioConverter.h in AudioToolbox soo if someone could please help me I would be really appreciative.

Thank You
Enea

Answer (score 4):

ExtAudioFile can do a fantastic job of this.  One reason to take some compressed formats like MP3 and convert to PCM is that there is much less of a latency when playing the sound.  An MP3 sound effect, for example, can take close to a second to start playing back, when the same sound in PCM could start almost immediately.  I know since I am converting my sounds to PCM at launch time and eliminating the delays I was plagued with.

Go download [iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/index.html) and you will find everything you need to do your own conversions

Comment: If latency is not an issue, then skip conversion and use AVAudioPlayer to play your MP3s.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real question is why would you want to?  The iphone and AudioQueue has full mp3 support for playback and mixing.  I know of no way to do this on the fly in the iPhone.  It is a fairly processor intensive task and I doubt you could do it efficiently on the iPhone anyway.

Comment: The reason I am trying to do this is beacuse my app downloads files in .m4r/.mp3 and for my purposes i need them in .caf and i was wondering if there is any way to instead of supplying a recording as packets to the speakhere example when it writes data to the file that is create if you could pass data from an mp3 file?

Comment: I suggest you look up apple docs or search on Stack Overflow as how to play a sound.  The speakhere example is a little old, and newer, easier methods are available

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExtAudioFile to open and convert the file to CAF with PCM data.